# Mutable list or array structure in Bash? How can I easily append to it?

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting

I'm trying to collect string values in a bash script. What's the simplest way that I can append string values to a list or array structure such that I can echo them out at the end?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
$ arr=(1 2 3)
$ arr+=(4)
$ echo ${arr[@]}
1 2 3 4
```

Since Bash uses sparse arrays, you shouldn't use the element count `${#arr}` as an index. You can however, get an array of indices like this:

```
$ indices=(${!arr[@]})
```

Answer (score 20):

```
foo=(a b c)
foo=("${foo[@]}" d)
for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo "$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to what Ignacio has suggested in another answer:

```
foo=(a b c)
foo=("${foo[@]}" d) # push element 'd'

foo[${#foo[*]}]="e" # push element 'e'

for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo "$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ for i in "string1" "string2" "string3"
> do
> array+=($i)
> done
$ echo ${array[@]}
string1 string2 string3
```

Answer (score 2):

The rather obscure syntax for appending to the end of an array in Bash is illustrated by the following example:

```
myarr[${#myarr[*]}]="$newitem"
```

Comment: As Dennis Williamson's answer points out, this is incorrect in some cases; bash arrays are sparse, and the index ${#myarr[*]} may not be the last index.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is answered and is pretty old, I'd like to share a namespace-solution as it works significantly faster than any other ways except for [ennukiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86837/ennuikiller)'s answer (on my 100k lines tests it won ~12 secs against my ~14 secs, whereas list-append solution would take a few minutes).

You can use the following trick:

```
# WORKS FASTER THAN THESE LAME LISTS! ! !
size=0;while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line
    ((++size))
    eval "SWAMP_$size='$line'"
done
```

Or you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
size=0
namespace="SWAMP"

ArrayAppend() {
    namespace="$1"
    # suppose array size is global
    new_value="$2"
    eval "${namespace}_$size='$2'"
    eval "echo \$${namespace}_$size"
    ((++size))
}

ArrayAppend "$namespace" "$RANDOM"
ArrayAppend "$namespace" "$RANDOM"
ArrayAppend "$namespace" "$RANDOM"
ArrayAppend "$namespace" "$RANDOM"
ArrayAppend "$namespace" "$RANDOM"
```

As long as the interpreter is in tag list, here's a link for [object oriented bash](https://sourceforge.net/projects/oobash/).

Comment: Don't use `eval` for assignment (especially on user input)! **your code is subject to code injection and is highly insecure** (and hence broken)! so… it's even lamer than lame lists `:)`.

Comment: By the way, if your only goal is to slurp your file line by line in an array, with Bash≥4 you should use `mapfile`: `mapfile -t lines < file`.

Comment: Though, if you ask, I can show you a very little known way of using `eval` safely…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, sure. I'd like to see that.

Comment: This is not the proper way to dynamically assign variables, but here's a safe and little known way: instead of `eval "$a=$b"` use `tmp=$b eval "$a"='$tmp'`. Though there are other better ways: `printf -v "$a" '%s' "$b"` or `declare "$a=$b"`.

Comment: But hey, the “lame list” is going to be much faster (and safer) if you use the proper tool: `mapfile -t lines < file`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, whereas lists are widely supported, although not POSIX-kosher, i can't find `mapfile` on my `zsh`.

Comment: `mapfile` is a Bash builtin (you're in a question tagged [tag:bash]).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, focusing on one implementation is a bad practice, to my mind. But yes, `eval` is an unsafe solution, although it reveals many shell's capabilities.